# The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, iis-7, rdlc

I am using `RDLC` reporting in a `ASP.Net Web Application`. In development version my `Reports` works perfectly but when i deploy it on `IIS` on Server, I got the below error.

I have checked the version of Report viewer, its same...

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

[image]

Comment: Is the RDLCs working fine on your development machine? What is the version of your framework?

Comment: Yes, its working on Development machine... Framework v 4.0

Comment: Ok. For testing purpose, create one blank RDLC and try to call it in your ASP.Net and see if you get the same error.  What is the version of your visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add below dll to /bin folder

   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
2. Expand File Publish Options, and then check Allow this precompiled 
   site to be updateable.

Comment: I was having this problem when try to view rdlc files from Azure web app. after applying 2 it  worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines from Web.config:

```
<buildProviders>
  <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
</buildProviders>
```